# export cassandra schema (all keyspaces and tables)

Tags: cassandra

I am going through the code of apache cassandra 2.2 branch, and unable to find where we can backup entire schema (including all keyspaces and tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to backup scheme than you can use `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE` in cqlsh

```sh
cqlsh $(hostname) -e "DESCRIBE KEYSPACE <keyspace>;" > backup.cql
```

To restore scheme you can simply do

```sh
cat backup.cql | cqlsh $(hostname)
```

**EDIT**

To describe keyspace programmatically via [thrift client](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples#Java). Compile client and then you can use [describe_keyspaces](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2/interface/cassandra.thrift#L837)/[describe_keyspace](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2/interface/cassandra.thrift#L799)

```java
Cassandra.Client client = ...
for (KDef keyspaceDefinition : client.describe_keyspaces()) {
    // process keyspace data
}
```

Comment: I know, how to achieve from cqlsh. I am looking for the class or function in cassandra code that actually does that work. I am referencing open source code in my project and need to run "describe schema" type feature from there.

Comment: @VarunGupta You can do it via thrift. Take a look [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2/interface/cassandra.thrift#L837)

Comment: @VarunGupta `describe schema` is build on top of `describe_keyspaces`.  Take a look [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2/bin/cqlsh.py#L1589)

Comment: where in apache cassandra code base, does it convert KsDef struct to string?

Comment: @VarunGupta afaik cqlsh uses python-driver feature to do it. You can find code [here](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/metadata.py#L651). You can build it the same way